# Is it possible to find the location of another android phone and send them some data?

Tags: java, android

i want to create an application that will get the location of other devices who are having this application. and if they are in range than sending them some data.

my project contains two application. one get the location of other devices who are having the another application and check whether they are in range if they are in range then send them some signal so they will get to know that the device is near them.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. This site is not for soliciting for work, paid or free, or for giving step by step tutorials. Instead, we ask you to show what you have attempted so far, and what specific problem or question you are stuck with.

Comment: Generally the easiest would be to have a server match up GPS locations reported by phones and inform nearby ones about each other's existence.  If you need greater accuracy it gets a bit challenging.

Comment: @ChrisStratton can you tell me some servers that i can use. and how to send the location to that server and fetch them back.

Comment: Those are indeed the tasks you should be researching.

Answer (score 0):

You should check Androidlost. Anyway, how do you want phones to exchange data? Over server using data packets (GPRS/WiFi)  or Bluetooth? I think that Nokia had a similar application to what you want to do. Maybe you should check their community developers site (for Simbian) if it is still active. I remember that service was capable of finding nearby friends phones and inform their owners about it by Bluetooth. It was convenient in dark crowded places such as night clubs, so you got notification when your friends arrive. Androidlost is checking position by GPS or by network location. It helps if WiFi is on. Best accuracy is 10 met and worst (network location) is around 2 km. Data is exchanged over androidlost Web server. Hope this helps. If you provide more info about your intentions we might help you better.

Comment: Androidlost is used to find the phone which is lost and it will used for only one phone. my application needs to find all the android phones having this application and notify them about the my position is nearby them if they gets in my range.

Comment: Although the goal is different, the functionality is similar enough to learn from

Comment: @user3599930 You miss the point of my answer - you should examine how Androidlost finds another phone(s). You can track multiple phones (I have 3 on single account). Although you have to manually switch and locate phone by phone. Besides locating phone, it can do many other things such as: start/stop wifi, gprs, gps, read messages, call logs, take pictures, record sound, wipe, format read SD card, erase whole phone, START APPLICATION of choice in short gaining remote control of other phone which is way more than you plan to do. You should contact Androidlost author and ask him for help.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You are right - OP misunderstood my answer and I think that OP haven't had detailed look of what Androidlost is really about. I pointed out to that particular application because I use it, but I know that there are applications on market to track (automatically, periodically and simultaneously) family members (for example - are the kids in school). Also there are apps to track fiends while together(for example) on mountain hiking etc. Anyway my guess is that he wants to accomplish (in general) what NOKIA application was doing (can't remember the name of app).